# htaccess pagination re-write rule

Tags: .htaccess, pagination

Can some one please help me with the htacess rewrite rule for pagination

I have my httacccess written as follows

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Everything works fine except with the pagination

my index.php has a pagination with link link index.php?page=2&ipp=5

How can i make my pagination to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before the rules that you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?page=([0-9]+)&([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3/%4?page=%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! but it isn't working, my paginator code looks like: <a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a>
Do i have to change to \ on link here

Comment: @PlanetZ What does "*Do i have to change to \ on link here*" mean?

Comment: I meant on the pagination.php page do I have to create a link for the pages as <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page\$i\ipp\$this->items_per-page">

Comment: @PlanetZ create the link the way you want it to look